# run startup.sh doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell-script

I downloaded [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/installing-tomee.html) zip file, extract it. The directory structure is like this:

```
apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1/
            - bin/
                -startup.sh
```

I added the following thing in my .bash_profile

```
export CATALINA_HOME=apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1
export PATH=$PATH:$CATALINA_HOME/bin
```

I run `source .bash_profile` .
Then, I run `startup.sh`
But I get error:

```
-bash: startup.sh: command not found
```

I then tried to run `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh` , I get error:

```
-bash: apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1/bin/startup.sh: No such file or directory
```

How to run startup.sh ?

Comment: Most likely your current directory is not directly above the expanded tomee files. Make CATALINA_HOME an absolute path and try again.

Comment: @JeffSchaller may as well post that as an answer.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, how to make CATALINA_HOME an absolute path? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: See my Answer....

Answer (score 2):

It's not explicit in your question, but you would get that "No such file or directory" error if you ran `startup.sh` from any directory other than the one that's directly above `apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1` because you've set CATALINA_HOME to `apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1` which is *not* an absolute path.

The reason this matters is because you then use it in `PATH`, which your shell uses to find executables. If there's a piece of the PATH variable that is *not* absolute (starts with `/`), then your shell will append that piece to your current directory.

The fix is simple -- make `CATALINA_HOME` have an absolute path as its value. Change directory *into* the expanded apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1 and run:

```
pwd
```

then use that resulting value in your .bash_profile as the CATALINA_HOME value.